# How to handle random bytestream when executing shell commands?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

I want to run arbitrary commands in the shell and get stdout and stderr, for example like this:

```
cmd = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, universal_newlines=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout = cmd.stdout
stderr = cmd.stderr
```

However, stdout and stderr might contain random bytestreams. This leads to errors like this:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfd in position 135: invalid start byte
```

How can I handle this? Stuff like � would be ok as result.

Comment: You shouldn't use `universal_newlines` with binary data, and you need to tell Python you want bytestrings back.

Comment: Quoting the docs: *The `universal_newlines` argument is equivalent to `text` and is provided for backwards compatibility. By default, file objects are opened in binary mode*

Comment: BTW, in general, I'd advise `shell=False` when at all possible, but _especially_ when running commands that generate arbitrary stdout. POSIXy shells use C strings, which are NUL-delimited and thus can't contain NULs in their text, so binary data is tricky to handle with a shell (impossible to handle, in many cases, with baseline `/bin/sh` implementations as `shell=True` uses by default). Granted, that's moot if the shell isn't capturing and processing the data, but if you aren't actually using the shell for anything important you don't need `shell=True` anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by `universal_newlines=True` causing your data to be read as text rather than as binary content. Remove that argument.